# How can I use ng-repeat and filter to get JSON data

Tags: javascript, angularjs

For the JSON below, if I want to get value of `name` for every object, how should I do it? `{{x}}` shows both value of `name` and `type`, but `{{x.name}}` or `{{x.type}}` doesn't work.

Also, If I use `{{x}}` to display name and type, how do I set a filter which can search value of `name`, but show the whole line, for example, I type A, then shows 'A file'.

**JSON:**

```
 $scope.test = [{"name":"A","type":"file"},{"name":"B","type":"folder"},{"name":"C","type":"folder"}]
```

Html:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="searchtext">    

<table>
    <tr>
        <th>NAME</th>
        <th>TYPE</th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="t in test">
        <td ng-repeat="x in t | filter: searchtext">
        {{x}}
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: have you tried `{{x['name']}}` instead??

Comment: I tried it, still not working, but {{x}} works

Comment: try using `ng-repeat="x in t.name...` . and then x will be only name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont know what `searchtext` is like, but I think this may give an idea:

```
<tr ng-repeat="x in test|filter:searchtext">
  <td>
    <span ng-bind="x.name"></span>
    <span ng-bind="x.type"></span>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

You may also try this code. However, I have added a div element instead of a table.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.8/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-app="app" ng-controller="t">

        <p><input type="text" ng-model="searchtext" /></p>

        <div ng-repeat="x in data | filter:searchtext">

            <div> {{ x.name + ' ' + x.type }} </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</body>

<script>
    var myApp = angular.module('app', []);
    myApp.controller('t', function ($scope) {
        $scope.data = [{ "name": "A", "type": "file" }, { "name": "B", "type": "folder" }, { "name": "C", "type": "folder"}];
    });
</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <tr ng-repeat="t in test">
     <td ng-repeat="(key,value) in t | filter: searchtext">
         {{value}}
     </td>
 </tr>
```

Comment: I thinks its `{{value}}`